# xdebug в phpstorm останавливается на первой строке

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Как сделать чтобы останавливался только на breakpoint-ах?

Comment: Настройки - PHP - Debug - Force break at the first line ?

Comment: https://habrastorage.org/files/9d6/fac/ada/9d6facada4e54639b93218e4d93082a6.png

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, все убрано.

Comment: скорее всего, у вас не настроены маппинги, в окне дебаггера должно появиться соообщение об этом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,  где это настроить?

Comment: вообще мапинги в Настройки - PHP - Servers - и там галочка есть `use path mappings`.....b там настраиваются.